# CGRectIntersectsRect with coordinates of object

Tags: objective-c, game-physics, cgpoint

I wanted to ask if there is something similar to the Code CGRectIntersectsRect.
For eg:
There is an object, and a block. If the object lands on the top of the Block, it can stay on it. If the object hits the left,right or bottom side of the Block, it should smash against it and fall down.
My Code :

```
   if(CGRectIntersectsRect(Object.frame, Block.frame)){
    ObjectJump = 0;
    }
```

But with that code, the object will stay even he jumps from the bottom to the top of the block. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: So you want to verify the direction of movement? Or the size of the intersection?

Comment: The Block is 40x40. If the Object jumps on the top of the Block, it should stay on it. If the Object hits the left/ right/ bottom side, it should fall down, not being able to stay.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intersection is checked repeatedly, so you know at the start of the intersection, then what matters is how much of the object is above the block and how much is below. If above > below then it's on top.

Currently you check for intersection, but you can also get the intersection of the frames. Once you have that you can compare the heights of the intersection frame and the object frame. If the object frame height > 2 * the intersection frame height then the frames don't overlap much. Assuming that the object can't be inside the block already this is enough information. If the object hit the side of the block then the intersection frame height would be the same as the object frame height.